# Handle multiple statements in Run Keyword If - Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm need to execute multiple statements only if the condition is passed using Robot Framework

Kindly look at the code : Note this is a sample code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    ${isElementExist}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=txt1
    Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}     click element      id=btn1
    Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}     click element      id=btn2
    Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}     click element      id=btn3

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for If Condition
    Parent Routine
```

I don't know how to bundle all the statements of `click element` under the scope of `Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}`.

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off-course we can execute multiple statements in `Run Keyword If`

The If Statement should be

```
Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}    Run Keywords    click element      id=btn1
...   AND    click element      id=btn2
...   AND    click element      id=btn3
```

The Complete Code is

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    ${isElementExist}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=txt1
    Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}    Run Keywords    click element      id=btn1
    ...   AND    click element      id=btn2
    ...   AND    click element      id=btn3

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for If Condition
    Parent Routine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Run Keywords` which will execute all the given keywords in a sequence.

```
${isElementExist}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=txt1
Run Keyword If    ${isElementExist}     Run Keywords    click element      id=btn1
...    AND    click element      id=btn2
...    AND    click element      id=btn3
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Test Variable    ${temp}    rxu
    Run Keyword if    '${temp}'=='rxu'
    ...    Run Keywords
    ...    Log To Console    this is one
    ...    AND    Log To Console    This is two
    ...    ELSE    Run Keyword    Log To Console    another block

Space before each line should confirm to python spacing guidelines